# Trajectories in phase space - Overflowerror: (34, 'Result too large')

Tags: python, ode

I am new to Python but I have prior experience in C++ and MATLAB. 
I am currently writing a program to plot trajectories in phase space for nonlinear systems involving dy/dt and dx/dt. However, for more complicated functional forms, I received the Overflow Error. Is there any way for me to circumvent this problem? Thanks in advance!

These are my codes:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,6))
dt = 0.01
def trajectories():
    #initial conditions
    x = y = 0.1
    xresult = [x]
    yresult = [y]
    for t in xrange(10000):
        # functional form: dx/dt = y, dy/dt = -r(x**2-1)*y-x
        nextx = x + (r*x-y+x*y**2) * dt
        nexty = y + (x + r*y + y**3) * dt
        x, y = nextx, nexty
        xresult.append(x)
        yresult.append(y)
    plt.plot(xresult, yresult)
    plt.axis('image')
    plt.axis([-3, 3, -3, 3])
    plt.title('r = ' + str(r))


rs = [-1, -0.1, 0, .1, 1]
for i in range(len(rs)):
    fig.add_subplot(1, len(rs), i + 1)
    r = rs[i]
    trajectories()
plt.show()

EDIT: this is the full traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Griffin/Atom/NumInt.py", line 33, in <module>
    trajectories()
  File "/Users/Griffin/Atom/NumInt.py", line 18, in trajectories
    nextx = x + (r*x-y+x*y**2) * dt
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: just added the full traceback. thanks!

Comment: your post code works fine for me. Im thinking about decimal precision of your data.... Your dt is fixed to 0.01? What happens for lower values?

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate error has to do with the fact that the Euler algorithm you are using for integration becomes unstable at the step size you are using. The ultimate problem is actually using the Euler algorithm. The code below uses `scipy.integrate.odeint` to handle the integration and does a better job due to being able to do variable step sizes. Some of the integration is still not perfect, but at least we get some results.

```
import numpy
import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def derivatives(states, t, r):
    x, y = states
    return [r*x - y + x*y**2,
            x + r*y + y**3]

def trajectories(r):
    initial_conditions = [0.1, 0.1]
    times = numpy.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
    result = scipy.integrate.odeint(derivatives, initial_conditions, times, args=(r,))
    xresult, yresult = result.T

    plt.plot(xresult, yresult)
    plt.axis('image')
    plt.axis([-3, 3, -3, 3])
    plt.title('r = ' + str(r))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,6))

rs = [-1, -0.1, 0, .1, 1]

for i, r in enumerate(rs, 1):  # Avoid for i in range(len(rs))
    fig.add_subplot(1, len(rs), i)
    trajectories(r)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: result of simulation]